# The return type 'int?' isn't a 'int', as required by the closure's contex

Tags: dart

The following:

```
  var sortedByValue = SplayTreeMap<int, String>.from(
      fruit, (key1, key2) => fruit[key1].compareTo(fruit[key2]));
```

complains about null safety, then I add "?" to `fruit[key1]?`, ok then I.... ahhh?

```
import 'dart:collection';

void splayTreeMapExample(){
  var fruit = SplayTreeMap<int, String>();

  fruit[0] = 'Banana';
  fruit[5] = 'Plum';
  fruit[6] = 'Strawberry';
  fruit[2] = 'Orange';
  fruit[3] = 'Mango';
  fruit[4] = 'Blueberry';
  fruit[1] = 'Apple';

  print(fruit);

  fruit.forEach((key, val) {
    print('{ key: $key, value: $val}');
  });

  var sortedByValue = SplayTreeMap<int, String>.from(
      fruit, (key1, key2) => fruit[key1]?.compareTo(fruit[key2]));

  print(sortedByValue);
}
```

Comment: Sorting a splay-tree map by value is *not* a good idea. Use a splay tree *set* instead.
You're basically ignoring the keys completely, and adding an extra lookup in the `fruit` map on every key operation.

Answer (score 1):

You got to love null safety(Null safety principles - Non-nullable by default, hmm, right - well it must be the "Map/fruit" return value):

```
fruit, (key1, key2) => fruit[key1]!.compareTo(fruit[key2]!));
```